# E is a Galois extension of F

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

> **15.32** Let $E$ be a finite extension of a field $F$ with dimension $n$. Show that $|\operatorname{Gal}_F(E)| = n$ if, and only if, $E$ is a Galois extension of $F$.

Please some help  to find the prove of Galois extension

Comment: I don't think that's true? Let $F=\mathbb Q$, and let $E=F/(x^3-2)$. Then the extension is of degree $3$, but the Galois Group, having the order $2$ complex conjugation automorphism in it, has order $6$.

Comment: in your case the galois group is trivial, since $F[x]/(x^3-2)$ does not have all 3 cube roots of 2. It's only got 1 of them.